# Nodejs - Javascript buffer that takes in uint64, enum and string data as input

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, protocol-buffers

I am writing a nodejs program that adds some data into a buffer, before it is streamed. The data types are listed in the comments of the code, and there are fixed places in the buffer that these data-types will appear. Is there any way I can optimise this code to run faster, or for the buffer to be smaller?

````
/*
`symbol`: utf-8 string up to 4 characters, 
`price`: unsigned 64-bit integer, 
`quantity`: unsigned 64-bit integer, 
`side`: enum buy | sell, 
`type`: enum limit | market
*/

const SIDE = {
  BUY: 0x01,
  SELL: 0x00
}

const TYPE = {
  LIMIT: 0x00,
  MARKET: 0x10
}

//test data
const data = new Map();
data.set('symbol', 'ETH');
data.set('price', BigInt.asUintN(64, '0x00000000000061A8')); 
data.set('quantity', BigInt.asUintN(64, '0x016345785D8A0000')); 
data.set('sideAndType', SIDE.BUY | TYPE.LIMIT); //save space by storing each enum in nybble and using bitwise operations


var buf = Buffer.alloc(21);

buf.write(data.get('symbol').padStart(4, '_'),0); //pad with illegal character
buf.writeBigUInt64BE(data.get('price'),4);
buf.writeBigUInt64BE(data.get('quantity'),12);
buf.writeUInt8(data.get('sideAndType'),20);

console.log(buf);```
````